ошибка при установке microsoft sql server management studio
При установке microsoft sql server management studio выдается ошибка

Нашел решение проблемы на сайте Ошибка (0x80070643) Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio
Решение: Откройте «Выполнить»> regedit> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager. Удалите PendingFileRenameperations
Но в обсуждении этой темы у всех PendingFileRenameperations находится в папке C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server...

В моем случае PendingFileRenameperations находится в Windows/system32...

Можно и безопасно ли удалять этот файл в таком случае? или нужно другое решение?

При установке просто выбирайте английский язык. Эта штука не поддерживает русский

так а что делать по итогу?

как раз тут русский язык очень хорошо поддерживается

Вы пробовали переустановить, как я написал выше?

удалить mssql server и установить на английском языке?

ну по сути в самом mssql нету как такового выбора языка (он всегда английский) а вот management studio я попробовал на английском и ничего не поменялось

не знаю получилось ли вам уже решить эту проблему.. но! сегодня сам столкнулся с той же ситуацией и мне помогло удаление microsoft odbc driver 17 for sql и перезапуск компьютера.

добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! стоило опубликовать это как комментарий, а не ответ. чтобы вам стали доступны комментарии к чужим сообщениям, надо набрать пятьдесят баллов репутации — это всего пять голосов «за» любой ваш ответ или вопрос
